# Nested For Loop Copies the last line in set of indicies

Tags: python, list, loops

```
    for each in Dti:
        i = 0
        for each in Dti[0]:
            xbi[t][i] = Dti[t][i]
            print(t)
            i = i + 1
        t = t + 1
```

this is just a test that I'm doing to figure out why my complicated code isn't working. I'm trying to iterate through a list and then each value in the list to set a new list of lists equal to that value. I know I could just set them equal to each other, but it needs to be done this way for my more complicated program. Any tips? I'm getting Dti[-1] for each xbi[t]. I've tried with while too and got the same results

Comment: `for each in Dti:` plus `for each in Dti[0]:` --> no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: and `t` isn't defined

Comment: "this is just a test that I'm doing to figure out why my complicated code isn't working" Thanks for trying to simplify your code for your question. It looks like you have simplified it too much because the code won't run as it is. For one thing, you are using the variable name `each` twice. And you are only looping over `Dti[0]`. Please work on your code example so that it is a fully running program. For more tips, read [mcve].

Comment: For figuring out what is going on in your actual code, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some debugging tips.

Comment: Also, check out the `enumerate()` function when you need the index of what you are iterating over in a for loop.

Comment: I think you want `for t in range(len(Dti)): for i in range(len(Dti[t])):`

Comment: What do you mean by "getting Dti[-1] for each xbi[t]`? Can you show an example of the original value of `Dti` and the result you're getting in `xbi`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for t, D in enumerate(Dti)
    for i, d in enumerate(D):
        xbi[t][i] = d
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing in assignments to replace one list's elements with the elements of another list:

```
for t, row in enumerate(Dti):
    xbi[t][:] = row
```